# How can I disable Magento 2 maintenance mode without using ssh

Tags: magento2

How can I disable the Magento 2 maintenance mode without using ssh?

On my server I don't have ssh. Can I disable the maintenance mode anyway?

[image: Screenshot showing error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is var/.maintenance.flag, Magento 2 maintenance mode is on. The only exception is related to var/.maintenance.ip. Since it can contain a list of IP addresses, a restriction occurs when an entry point is accessed via HTTP and the client IP address corresponds to an entry from the list. Thus, Magento 2 maintenance mode is off even if there is var/.maintenance.flag.

The following commands are associated with Magento 2 maintenance mode:
magento maintenance:enable [--ip= ... --ip=] | [ip=none]